# Wordpress API returns 404 on OSX (permalinks are enabled)

Tags: wordpress, macos, .htaccess, api, http-status-code-404

I've installed the [**rest-api 2.0beta9**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) module of [**wordpress 4.4**](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/download/) on [**El Capitan OSX 10.11.2**](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205579).

I've changed `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to run as my user so that it can easily update `Sites` files:

```
User jtosey
Group staff
```

I've also enabled `AllowOverride All` in the user conf:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/users/jtosey.conf 
<Directory "/Users/jtosey/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    LanguagePriority en fr de
    ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    # required for REST API:
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I've changed my permalinks, which caused `.htaccess` to be created:

```
$ cat /Users/jtosey/Sites/wordpress/.htaccess

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~jtosey/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~jtosey/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can easily curl the homepage:

```
$ curl http://localhost/~jtosey/wordpress/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
<title>AAA &#8211; Car Culture</title>
```

But I get a 404 on the API:

```
$ curl http://localhost/~jtosey/wordpress/wp-json/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /~jtosey/wordpress/wp-json/ was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I was missing a line in Apache config.  If you come across a similar problem, these are the exact config changes I made to get this to work, apart from installing the Wordpress REST plugin and enabling it:

```
$ diff /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf~orig
166c166
< LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
---
> #LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
168,169c168,169
< LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
< LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
---
> #LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
> #LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
181,183c181,182
< 
< User jtosey
< Group staff
---
> User _www
> Group _www
259c258
<     AllowOverride All
---
>     AllowOverride None
494c493
< Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
---
> #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
542,554d540
< # from brew install phpmyadmin
< Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
< <Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
<   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
<   AllowOverride All
<   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
<     Require all granted
<   </IfModule>
<   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
<     Order allow,deny
<     Allow from all
<   </IfModule>
< </Directory>
```

Next:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/users/jtosey.conf 
<Directory "/Users/jtosey/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    LanguagePriority en fr de
    ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
    # Wordpress - FollowSymLinks required for permalinks
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    # Wordpress API - required
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And lastly the following, which was created by phpadmin:

```
$ cat /Users/jtosey/Sites/wordpress/.htaccess 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~jtosey/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~jtosey/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Don't forget:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

When you're done.